# xsp npgsql C#.aspx

Tags: c#, mono, npgsql

Running: on bsd unix in a controlled environment with matching builds.
Running: xsp4 --port 8022 --nonstop --verbose
This works perfectly with C# until I add using npgsql; to the C# program:
Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name `Npgsql' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Note: I can create and run a mono program no errors with this directive:
mcs -r:/sdf/sys/pkg6_amd64/lib/mono/4.0/Npgsql -r:System.Data Npgsql1.cs
I have tried the npgsql and mono web site, stack overflow, google. Please suggest how to start xsp4 so npgsql can be found.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the error web page "'Npgsql' could not be found."
There was a link to compiler options and the second link one was
libs=myhomepage/bin
I copied the Npgsql.dll into that bin directory and it worked perfectly.
David